# Open QR scanner from custom keyboard button

Tags: android, keyboard, qr-code, zxing, custom-keyboard

I simply have a button "Scan" on the custom keyboard and that should open the qr code reader and return result to webview textbox after scanning. Scan button has keycode -101 in the customkeyboard.xml.

```
    <Key android:codes="-101" android:keyLabel="Scan" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
```

and I try to do something with the button here

```
public class keyboard extends InputMethodService
    implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

private KeyboardView kv;
private Keyboard keyboard;

private boolean caps = false;

@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
    playClick(primaryCode);
    switch (primaryCode) {
        case -101:
            Intent qrIntent = new Intent();
            qrIntent.setClass(keyboard.this, QRscanner.class);
            qrIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(qrIntent);
            break;

        default:
            char code = (char) primaryCode;
            if (Character.isLetter(code) && caps) {
                code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
            }
            ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code), 1);
    }
}
```

These added into gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
```

And camera permission into manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
```

There are plenty of exmples about ZXing, but not so much how to run it from custom keyboard and add result into webview textbox.

Thanks.

Comment: Post that as a comment on the answer, not as a new question.

Comment: Cannot do that, not enought reputations (new here)... Saw you did that, thanks.